# C++ objects as parameters for interface methods

Tags: c++, windows, dll, com

For my C++ DLLs, I am using the factory pattern with abstract interfaces.
In the disadvantages section of [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL#CppMatureApproach), it says:

> An abstract interface method cannot return or accept a regular C++ object as a parameter. It has be either a built-in type (like int, double, char*, etc.) or another abstract interface. It is the same limitation as for COM interfaces.

Could you elaborate what this means? What exactly can I not do and why?
Is there any further reading available on this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement does not look accurate. Abstract interface method can return or accept C++ class instance (or its pointer) as parameter. There is no COM-like limitation here. It might be unsafe though in case caller/callee are built using different compiler settings, alignments, using different allocators etc. in which case the same C++ class is defined slightly differently and the mismatch might result in unexpected behavior. That is, it is not about "cannot", it is about it might lead to unobvious problems.

A frequent example of the problem in question is passing `CString` as a parameter:

- [function in dll doesn't receive CString argument value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947942/function-in-dll-doesnt-receive-cstring-argument-value)